# Using if/then statements to parse argv[ ] options in C++

Tags: c++, if-statement, argv

How would you use an if/then statement using argv[], upon the option/parameter entered?

For example, *a.out -d 1 sample.txt* versus *a.out -e 1 sample.txt*.

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  ifstream infile(argv[3]);

  int c;
  int number = 0;
  int count = 0;

  while ( infile.good() ) {

            if (argv[1] == "-d")
            {

                 c = infile.get();

                 number = atoi(argv[2]);  

                  if (number == count)
                 {
                 cout.put(c);
                 count = 0;
                 }

                      else
                        count++;

            }       


           if (argv[1] == "-e")
           { 
              cout << "entered -e" << endl;   //testing code
           }


  }//end while

}//end main
```

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11106062/are-command-line-arguments-some-strings

Comment: Is your code giving an error ?

Comment: Could you please restate you question? What was your problem exactly?

Comment: @AshRj - no error, but when I run a.out, nothing happens for -d and -e.

Comment: @harman2012 It is because program not pass to while() body

Comment: @harman2012 Its probably because of the incorrect comparisons

Comment: @Sergey Do you mean I have to put  the c, number, count declarations in the while() body?

Comment: @harman2012 I've edit you question to make more sence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use the equality operator to compare C-style strings, you have to use [`std::strcmp`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcmp):

```
if (std::strcmp(argv[1], "-d") == 0)
```

The reason behind that is that the `==` operator compares the *pointers* not what they point to.

---

Since the C++14 standard, there's a [literal operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%22%22s) to turn a literal string into a `std::strinng` object which can be used for comparisons using `==`:

```
if (argv[1] == "-d"s)
```

Please note the trailing `s` in `"-d"s`.

Answer (score 1):

I hope you want to check the input parameter **-d** or **-e**, right?
if that is the case please use strcmp()

if (!strcmp(argv[1],"-d"))
            {

```
            count++;
            printf("\ncount=%d",count);

        }       

       if (!strcmp(argv[1],"-e"))
       { 
          printf("entered -e");   //testing code
       }
```

Answer (score 1):

The first error is in the very first line of `main`:

```
ifstream infile(argv[3]);
```

You cannot write that because *there is no third argument*. When you invoke your program like this:

```
a.out -d 1 < sample.txt
```

then the command line that the program sees looks like this:

```
argv[0] = "a.out"
argv[1] = "-d"
argv[2] = "1"
```

The `< sample.txt`, by contrast, is interpreted by the shell directly, and the file is streamed to the standard input of your program – and there’s nothing you can do to change that, inside your program.

As for the parsing itself, don’t do it *inside* the loop which reads the file, do it before and set appropriate flags.

For the actual parsing I’d suggest using a library to spare you a lot of pain. The standard Unix tool is [`getopt`](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Getopt.html) but that’s only got a C interface. There are several C++ libraries, amongst them [Boost.Program_Options](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/program_options.html) which is a tad too complex for my taste, though.

Comment: Thanks everyone! I did have to change it to string compare, strcmp didn't work when I changed a few things.

Answer (score 1):

The argc/argv comes from C and is rather cumbersome to use, so when more than basic argument passing is done, you can transform the arguments to a vector of strings and work in a C++ style:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  std::vector<std::string> args;
  std::transform(argv+1, argv+argc, std::back_inserter(args), [](char* arg){ return std::string(arg); });

  if (args.at(1) == "-d") { std::cout << "Arg 1 = -d" << "\n"; }

  for (auto& arg: args) { std::cout << "arg: " << arg << "\n"; }
}
```

Still, you need to check that the argument is present.  If this is a basic tool and it is acceptable that the tool aborts when the parameter is not present, then you can access args elements with `args.at(x)` instead of `args[x]`

Or check [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/253556/what-parameter-parser-libraries-are-there-for-c) for an argument parser.

Answer (score 0):

char *argv[] is an array of char **
so

```
 if (string(argv[1]) == "-d")
```